# My program takes too long to go through these if statements

Tags: python, if-statement

Is there a more efficient way than what I have written below as the program takes 10-15 seconds to compare the last if statement with the variable. The program is written in python. I want the program to near enough instantly compare and check if the value is equal.

```
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("Luna"):
    keyboard.type("lunar")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("lunar"):
    keyboard.type("lunar")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("asteroids"):
    keyboard.type("asteroids")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(3)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("asteroid"):
    keyboard.type("asteroids")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(3)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("universe"):
    keyboard.type("universe")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("orbit"):
    keyboard.type("orbit")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break        
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("Corbett"):
    keyboard.type("orbit")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("phases"):
    keyboard.type("phases")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("faces"):
    keyboard.type("phases")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("daisies"):
    keyboard.type("phases")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("satellite"):
    keyboard.type("satellite")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("Galaxy"):
    keyboard.type("galaxy")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("meteor"):
    keyboard.type("meteor")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(3)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("astronaut"):
    keyboard.type("astronaut")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("atmosphere"):
    keyboard.type("atmosphere")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("gravity"):
    keyboard.type("gravity")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
if r.recognize_google(audio) == ("eclipse"):
    keyboard.type("eclipse")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break
```

I am sort of a beginner at programming so any support is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't call `r.recognize_google()` each time. Call it once, save the result in a variable, and compare the variable. Also, use `elif` when checking mutually-exclusive conditions.

Comment: Also, once you get the code working and have complete code, post this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) to get suggestions. I could help you make this much neater.

Comment: `r.recognize_google(audio)` is probably a very expensive operation, and you’re repeating it for every case. Do it *once* and store the result in a variable.

Comment: @Carcigenicate There is a break at the end of each if, so it won't run it multiple times

Comment: @azro It will run it multiple times until it gets a match.

Comment: @azro It will if the checks fail.

Comment: It's a Speech-To-Text API which was free. Also, how would I include that into my program? I don't know how to call a function once. Thanks.

Comment: Why is there a break ? Is this in a loop of method ?

Comment: @Bluecider I don't think he means "expensive" regarding price, but computationally expensive.

Comment: Can the result of recognize_google match multiple if ? Or the result can be only one of them ?

Comment: You can also use `in ('Luna', 'lunar')` to test against multiple values when the result is the same.

Comment: @Barmar I just realised how stupid I look. lol

Comment: You don't know how to call a function once? `result = r.recognize_google(audio)`.

Comment: Yes, it's in a loop within a loop as I couldn't find another solution.

Comment: Each of your blocks is essentially identical, parameterized by a single string derived from an audio clip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`r.recognize_google(audio)` looks like it's probably a very slow function. It likely sends a request to Google, then waits for a response. Doing this needlessly over and over will take awhile, and will probably get you throttled by Google which will make the problem worse.

Call it once, then use the response multiple times:

```
response = r.recognize_google(audio)  # Save it once

if response == "Luna":  # Then use it multiple times
    keyboard.type("lunar")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break

elif response == "lunar":
    keyboard.type("lunar")
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    time.sleep(2)
    keyboard.press(Key.enter)
    keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    break

elif . . .
```

Comment: Maybe the 6 lines into could be written once too, just set a variable for the text

Comment: @azro Yes, that's why I suggested they post this on Code Review after once they have full working code. A full review is far beyond the scope of the question here. I would love to though, so I hope they take me up on my suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be working much much faster. I will upload the new code to code review now.

Comment: @Bluecider NOTE THOUGH: They have strict rules about code being posted. It must generally be full, runnable code that works as intended. Partial code is typically not allowed. They also require context, like a description of the code.

Comment: I will be sure to do that @Carcigenicate

Answer (score 0):

im not sure  but seems like your code is in such a format

```
if equal a:
  type b
  press key
  release key
  sleep time
  press key
  release key
```

which press key is same, that means you can have a dict and a function like:

```
dictx = {
  input1 : [type1, sleeptime1],
  input2 : [type2, sleeptime2],
  ...
}

def action(ans):
  type, sleeptime = dictx[ans]
  keyboard.type(type)
  keyboard.press(Key.enter)
  keyboard.release(Key.enter)
  time.sleep(sleeptime)
  keyboard.press(Key.enter)
  keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

and just call the function